# How to fix error "Oracle developer Tools For Visual Studio is not configured properly" in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, ado.net, oracle.manageddataaccess

1. I installed Visual Studio 2019 on my computer
2. I installed ODT for Visual Studio 2019(ODTforVS2019_133100) on my computer.
3. I started Visual studio 2019 new MVC application.
4. Via NugetPackages:

   - I installed EntityFramwdork
   - I installed Oracle.ManagedDataAccess
   - I installed Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramewok
5. I want to add Models->Add->New Item->Data->ADO.Net Entity Data Model.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am getting the error shown above. Please help with this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2019 can not be installed properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61930556/oracle-developer-tools-for-visual-studio-2019-can-not-be-installed-properly)

Comment: [Can't create a server connection with Oracle Tools for Visual Studio](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4268751/cant-create-a-server-connection-with-oracle-tools-for-visual-studio-2017)

Comment: It's hardy possible to read the screenshots, please provide error messages as text. (NB, "Ctrl+C" is your friend, it works also on error message box)

Answer (score 1):

**Error:**
Oracle Developer Tools For Visual Studio is not configured properly. Do you want to fix the configuration?
Failed to fix the configuration. Please try uninstalling and installing Oracle Developer Tools For Visual Studio.

I also encountered the same error message. I fixed the error. Follow the steps below in order.

1. Make sure Visual Studio 2019 is closed.
2. Open “C:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\community\common7\ide\devenv.exe.config” with notepad.
3. Add the following code block into the “configuration/system.data/DbProviderFactories” tag.
4. You can try to reconnect to the database by starting Visual Studio 2019.

```
<remove invariant="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" />
<add name="ODP.NET, Unmanaged Driver" invariant="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Unmanaged Driver" type="Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.122.19.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
<remove invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />
<add name="ODP.NET, Managed Driver" invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.122.19.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
```

> In fact, we have manually applied the configuration work that the ODT for VS extension tries to do at startup.

Please let me know your results.